# App to transfer photo from Android to Windows (except .nomedia folders)

Tags: windows

I'm looking for an easy-to-use (free) app to transfer pictures that are on an Android phone to Windows 10.

I would like this app to filter out the folders having a *.nomedia* file, or at least let me enable this option. Or if this really doesn't exist I would like it to let me specify which folders of the phone to monitor.

Moreover, pictures are mainly stored on the SD card (ie. external storage)

Unfortunately, Win10's built-in Photos app doesn't filter *.nomedia* folders out.

That's because there are a lot of images from other folders that are displayed (especially thumbnails it seems...) during import.

Comment: There are several [apps to backup photos](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_1090) (link goes to my own Android site), maybe one of them could help?

Comment: I'll have a look although I'm not really fond of adding apps to the phone. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want an app coming into play, that leaves you with scripting it yourself. No idea how well that works on Windows (where you could do that only via MTP); on Linux you could use something like `adbfs` to directly access the Android file system and walk the folders using a shell script. But yeah, maybe someone wrote a Windows application for that – so hopefully someone recommends it (I left Windows 25 years agi, so I'm not really familiar with that system). Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this over SMB (setup a file share on the computer), then use the [Solid Explorer Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) to "map" the share. Then you could copy all files (.nomedia should be hidden by default on Android) via Solid Explorer to the SMB share.

You could leverage ROBOCOPY on Windows to copy folders and exclude the .nomedia files too.

There may be other apps that let you access a Windows SMB share too, and I know of the opposite apps - where your android can host an SMB share that Windows can access.

Alternatively I know there are ways of accessing MTP (Android files when plugged into a PC) using PowerShell but this would be a code challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I just set up OneDrive, which has automatic photo sync of specified folders.  It's easy to use and has the added advantage of cloud storage/backup.

I have their office365 family plan (1TB/user for up to 6 users) and just added my MIL to that.  She wasn't very tech-savvy, so occasionally she would get signed out for some dumb reason, and I'd have to fix it, but other than that it works pretty seamlessly.